# SyncFramework 2.1 updates & deletes do not seem to apply properly

Tags: wcf, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm synchronizing SQL Server 2008 with ~6 SQL Server 2008 Express clients (everything R2 I believe), using the SyncOrchestrator or specifically using http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208 as a base with slight modifications. To my knowledge this means all connections are peers or nodes.

I have 2 scopes. One is download only and the other is upload only. The download only scope is ridden with identity columns primarily because I didn't know any better and still couldn't wrap my head around introducing Guids as the PK on the client side. It doesn't totally matter as all clients should have exact replicas of about 8 or so tables and these machines don't touch this data in any way, only read it.

The upload only scope uses Guids as fortunately I can control that portion of the database and there would be no way 10 clients all using the same identity seed could sync back to the server properly. Both scopes use the default provisioning with bulk inserts and the whole 9 yards so there shouldn't be anything I'm doing on the provisioning end to screw this up.

I initially set everything up not using PerformPostRestoreFixup AND the initial database would be manually synchronized with insert statements from the host. This seemed fine but no updates or deletes seemed to ever be applied. You can safely ignore this (only used for historical accuracy and to prove my ineptness) as I then used VS2010 Database Projects to rebuild the database down to schema only & synchronized. I then used the steps outlined here (http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/br/syncdevdiscussions/thread/9ac6d1a1-1565-4b82-a8d8-3d4a9ff5d07b) (sync, backup, restore, call performpostrestorefixup, sync on x clients) and on my dev box where I'm setting all this up I could see updates and deletes just fine. Its when I deploy this to the x clients that I'm not seeing a mirror of the database as I think I should.

The initial sync will complain and try to synchronize all records again. I believe this is expected. During ApplyChangeFailed event on the client I set everything other than DbConflictType.ErrorsOccurred to ApplyAction.RetryWithForceWrite. This may be a source of problems as I initially thought this should be done to force the change down to the client. I want the server to always win in this scenario but during trace I always see the phrase "Local wins" during the bulk insert/update calls. It's possible I'm seeing the error before the re-apply happens but it's awkward to look at.

The only problem I seem to be having is with the download only scope. The initial client database is about a week old now and if I use the performpostrestorefixup steps I don't see any of the updates that have applied between now and then as I think I should. It's as if SyncFx almost prefers a blank database on the client side to kick off the initial sync then all the updates seem to apply just fine with no ApplyChangesFailed events kicking off.

If anyone has seen this before or has a clue where to go I would greatly appreciate it. My brain has fried trying to determine what it is that's going on. My last ditch effort will be to deploy blank databases to all the clients and have them start the sync. I've had no issues with this on the dev side but I can only test one other client to know if that'll do anything different. Aside from that I don't know what to do other than to keep doing manual syncs which would defeat this purpose entirely. I thought PerformPostRestoreFixup would alleviate the issue entirely but I seem to be having the same problems with or without it or perhaps I'm not looking at what I need to be.

Thanks

Comment: on the download scope you mentioned, do you get anything on the ApplyChangesFailed event or it simply doesnt download any change?

Comment: Yeah sorry I should've mentioned that. Download always kicks off ApplyChangesFailed with either LocalUpdateRemoteUpdate or LocalInsertRemoteInsert. What I don't get is the clients don't touch any of these tables whatsoever.

One thing that may point to the issue is there is a ModifiedOn (datetime) field but code was just recently introduced to update this. The database doesn't use this as rowversion but it's possible there's something I haven't configured in the schema correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to report and close the entry with my findings.

When I would deploy a previously configured client database, I'd often get ApplyChangeFailed events in the form of this log:

"[05:30:41 PM] - ApplyChange Failed:    TableName: , Stage: ApplyingInserts, ConflictType: LocalInsertRemoteInsert, Action: RetryWithForceWrite"

This is what I thought would be expected as it tried to reinsert the data that is already there. What this should've been changed to was an update statement during RetryWithForceWrite but I found the data was not updating with what was being sent down.

Once I started each client with a completely blank database and provisioned locally, all of these errors went away. It's as if every client expects some unique id only it sets. I'm also using x64 builds versus x86 which may have some or no bearing on the results. I wish I could determine what exactly happened but it seems that when in doubt, and whenever possible, starting from absolute zero and letting sync fill in the data is your safest option.

Comment: The only discrepancy of all this is that sync runs every 30 minutes and some changes apply across thresholds meaning I can count 17 updates between an hour but certain clients touch 14 + 3, some 16 + 1, etc. As long as I get the final result eventually I'm happy. It's likely having something to do with time on the server I would bet.