# Sync framework 2.1 with SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server CE doesn't sync inserts and dowload all updates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using the Sync framework 2.1 with SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server CE with several clients.

I provisioned the client db and synced, then deployed that file with every client application.

Now sync doesn't seem to work correctly on all but one client. Did I need to provision the db for each client independently instead of using a copy?

This question does suggest so, please advise [SyncFramework 2.1 updates & deletes do not seem to apply properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193915/syncframework-2-1-updates-deletes-do-not-seem-to-apply-properly)

Answer (score 2):

in Sync Fx, each replica has a unique id to differentiate it from the other replicas. by copying a database, you'll end up with several replicas having the same id.

so what your doing will not work. if you want use a provisioned SQL CE database to initialize other clients, generate a snapshot and deploy the snapshot.

see: [How To: Provision for Synchronization Using Snapshot Initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882038.aspx)

Comment: Thanks June. Just a clarification, can I deploy the same copy of a snapshot to all other clients or do I have to generate a snapshot for every client.

Comment: You can deploy the same snapshot to every client. Make sure its the snapshot that you deploy. Once you have synched a snapshot once, Sync Fx no longer treats that database as a snapshot. i.e., you create a snapshot, you can send that to as many clients as you want. If client A syncs its snapshot, you can't use client A's database to initialize other clients because once a database snapshot is synched, its metadata is updated and is no longer treated a snapshot